# What is this black box on top of my radon fan?

Tags: radon

I am in the process of replacing my RadonAway RP145 fan (15 years old).

What is this black box on top of the fan?

I cannot find any info about what it is used for and if that needs to be replaced too.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since you're replacing the fan anyway,  remove the black box and check it out. It could be a check valve or a filter.  It looks like it just unscrews and you could see what's inside. There might be some identifying markings on the back side.

Comment: Yes, it's probably a backflow prevention device.